# Upgrading CakePHP from 2.8.0 to 2.10.20

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.8

Currently, I have a live project in CakePHP **2.8.0** where PHP Version is **5.6.40**.
I need to upgrade my CakePHP to the latest version. Can you suggest any new version that I should upgrade to without having many changes? Should I upgrade to 2.10.20 which is the 2019 release? Also, I **don't** want to change the PHP version which is 5.6.40 now.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrades to CakePHP need to be done iteratively, ie. you'd need to cover everthing in the 2.9 migration guide before going through the 2.10 migration guide.

I'd suggest taking a copy of your code and installing the most recent version of CakePHP 2.10 for it and going through the [CakePHP 2.9 Migration guide](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/appendices/2-9-migration-guide.html) and then the [CakePHP 2.10 Migration guide](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/appendices/2-10-migration-guide.html)

Both 2.9 and 2.10 are compatible with PHP 5.6

After doing this, you can consider upgrading to CakePHP 3 which is a much bigger upgrade